# Win32DiskImager - Error 121: The semaphore timeout period has expired

Tags: sd-card, win32diskimager

I'm not able to write on my SD card with Win32DiskImager. I throws the error:

> An error occurred when attempting to write data to handle. Error 121 The semaphore timeout period has expired

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with older (read: slower) SD cards. If I recall correctly, the creator had significant problems with cards that were lower than class 6.

You may be able to fix the issue by running `chkdsk` on the card (requires admin rights). If that doesn't work, you'll probably need to buy a different SD card. At the very least I'd try a different card reader.